# merging two columns together Month and Year as MMM-YYYY

Tags: sql

I have two columns First Column `(MMM-Month)` Second Column `(YYYY-Year)`

I would like to amalgamate these two columns to have `MMM-YYYY` in the next column.

tried to cast both columns into one but only could get the year

```
cast(convert(varchar(6),c.Year,112) as int)[Month/Year]
```

Comment: How are the columns defined and which database are you using?

Comment: c.CalendarMonthShortName as Month,   c.Year and I'm using IAndrew.dbo.WardClosures_Midnight joined to [iCS.Warehouse3].lk.Calendar

Comment: What are the data types for First & Second columns?

Comment: I think the Month Column is Varchar and the Year column is Int

Comment: @JustLee . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
month + '-' + convert(varchar(6),year,112)[Month/Year]
```

Comment: This also worked, thank you for your swift response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running SQL server DB, below is the code based on my understanding of the question

```
c.CalendarMonthShortName + '-' + CAST(c.Year as varchar(4))
```

Comment: Thank you Mihun this worked perfectly,Sorry if my Questions/Answers didn't give anything away, I am really new to SQL and my role

Comment: @MidhunJoy . . . You should *always* include a length with `varchar`.  The default varies by context and using the default can cause hard-to-debug errors.